# Can I use an if statement inside of a switch in php?

Tags: php, forms, if-statement, switch-statement

Heres what I want to do:

I have a variable named $user, where the information is being POSTED from a form. If the form data is empty I want to do one thing, if the form data is just a comma or symbol I want to do another thing, and if the form data is correct I want to do a third thing. This is how I have it set up, will this work? If not, what can I do to make it work?

```
switch($user){
    case 1:
if(empty($user)){
echo "<h2>"."<strong>"."You entered NOTHING, PLEASE Re-Enter"."</strong>"."</h2>";
}
case 2:
if($user == ",") {
echo "<h2>"."<strong>"."You did not enter any valid names/abbreviations to search, PLEASE Re-Enter"."</strong>"."</h2>";
}
default:


    print "==========================================="."<br />";
    tester($company, $user);


print "==========================================="."<br />";
print "========The following were NOT found====="."<br />";
notFound($company, $user);

print "==========================================="."<br />";

}
```

Right now it is automatically going to default. It runs, but I want integrate the two qualifiers, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put `break` at the end of each case in a switch statement or it falls through to the next case. I also think you may be confused about the way `switch` works. If you're switching on $user, `case` matches against the value of $user--so you don't even need if-statements.

```
switch($user){
    case "":
        echo "<h2>"."<strong>"."You entered NOTHING, PLEASE Re-Enter"."</strong>"."</h2>";
        break;
    case ",":
        echo "<h2>"."<strong>"."You did not enter any valid names/abbreviations to search, PLEASE Re-Enter"."</strong>"."</h2>";
        break;
    default:
        print "==========================================="."<br />";
        tester($company, $user);


        print "==========================================="."<br />";
        print "========The following were NOT found====="."<br />";
        notFound($company, $user);

        print "==========================================="."<br />";
}
```

Comment: GREAT! That worked just the way I wanted it to, thank you very much

Comment: One more thing, if more than one comma is input then it goes to default, how can I make it so that any number of consecutive commas has the same result?

Comment: `switch` isn't really the best way to do that--you're going to have to look into regex. To match commas you'd do `preg_match("/,+/", $user)`